# ObjectInputStream DeadLock

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm developing a client-server app, and my server can receive connection requests from 2 types of clients, therefore I instanciate the ObjectInputStream directly in my server, to recognize the client type (client or worker) and then I have a Thread for each type of client.

While initializing the thread, I pass as an argument the socket which I created in the server. (code below)

```
public class Server {

public int PORT;
private ArrayList<DealWithClient> connectedClients;
private ArrayList<DealWithWorker> connectedWorkers;
private ArrayList<String> types = new ArrayList<>();
private BlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new BlockingQueue<>();
private SearchTypes searchTypes;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Server(args[0]);
}

public Server(String port) {
    this.PORT = Integer.parseInt(port);
    startServing();
}

public void startServing() {
    connectedClients = new ArrayList<>();
    connectedWorkers = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println("Lançou ServerSocket: " + s);    
        try {
            while (true) {
                Socket socket = s.accept();
                inscription(socket);
            }
        } finally {
            s.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void inscription(Socket socket) {
    try {
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        Object obj = in.readObject();
        if(obj instanceof String) {
            String inscriptionMessage = (String) obj;
            System.out.println("Mensagem recebida: " + obj);
            if(inscriptionMessage.contains("Inscrição cliente")) {
                DealWithClient dwc = new DealWithClient(socket, this);
                dwc.start();
                addClient(dwc);
                out.writeObject(searchTypes);
            }
            if(inscriptionMessage.contains("Inscrição worker")) {
                String[] worker = inscriptionMessage.split(" ");
                searchTypes = new SearchTypes(worker[4]);
                DealWithWorker dww = new DealWithWorker(socket, this);
                dww.start();
                addWorker(dww);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void addClient(DealWithClient client) {
    connectedClients.add(client);
    System.out.println("Cliente adicionado! »» " + client.toString());
}

public void addWorker(DealWithWorker worker) {
    connectedWorkers.add(worker);
    System.out.println("Worker adicionado! »» " + worker.toString());
}
```

My DealWithClient code below, is where I'm having the problem, since that I can not reach the System.out.println("BBB"), because it gets stuck in the instanciation of ObjectInputStream.

```
public class DealWithClient extends Thread{

private Socket socket;
private Server server;
private ObjectInputStream in;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private Client client;

public DealWithClient(Socket socket, Server server) {
    this.server = server;
    this.socket = socket;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        connectToServer();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    while(!interrupted()) {
        treatClientRequests();
    }
}

private void connectToServer() throws IOException {

    out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    System.out.println("AAA");

    in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
    System.out.println("BBB");
}
```

I've looked for similar questions around here, but I didn't managed to find one that could solve my issue.
My question is, once I instanciate the ObjectInput and ObjectOutput streams in the server, I cannot do it again inside my Thread?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely getting a deadlock error because the socket is still being used by `ObjectOutputStream` when you are trying to get an Input stream from the same socket. Try calling the `close()` method on `out` before instantiating the `ObjectInputStream` below. Calling the `close()` method will free up resources.

Comment: If I understood correctly you are saying that on my class `DealWithClient`, on method `connectToServer()`, to call `close()` method, after the instantiation of `out`? If I do so, I have `java.net.SocketException: socket closed`..

Comment: what you could try next is to make a copy of the `socket` object and open an inputstream on that copied socket.